# Exclude folders containing string from nginx location block

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to apply a nginx-req-limit to all access attempts apart from those that include the word tiles.

eg

```
/assets/tiles/11391
```

so far I have

```
location ~ ^/tiles/ {
limit_req zone=one burst=15 nodelay;
}
```

The zone is defined in my nginx.conf file.

Is this correct?

Comment: Absolutely not. The `location` block will match URIs that **begin** with `/tiles/`, and the example you show, begins with `/assets/`. The `^` is an anchor for the beginning of the URI - not a negation of the regular expression,

Answer (score 1):

Richard already indicated the issue in your configuration. You can reach your objective with this configuration:

```
location / {
    limit_req zone=one burst=15 nodelay;
}

location ~ /tiles/ {
}
```

You may need to add additional directives to the `location` blocks in order to actually serve the files.